# Exploring device Logs

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung

If an android phone was off and/or the user couldn't login using the password provided, is it likely that this information is recorded in an log ?

Equally if a signal loss occurred would that be logged ?

And where or how can I access logs ?